# Take an element of a tensor which is inside also in another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors and I have to iterate on the first to take only the element that is inside the other tensor. There is only one element in `t2` that it is also inside `t1`. Here an example

```
t1 = tf.where(values > 0) # I get some indices example [6, 0], [3, 0]
t2 = tf.where(values2 > 0) # I get [4, 0], [3, 0]

t3 = .... # [3, 0]
```

I've tried to evaluate and iterate over them using `.eval()` and checked if an element of `t2` is in `t1` using the operator `in`, but doesn't work. Is there a function from TensorFlow that can do that?

**edit**

```
for index in xrange(max_indices):
    indices = tf.where(tf.equal(values, (index + 1))).eval() # indices: [[1 0]\n [4 0]\n [9 0]]
    cent_indices = tf.where(centers > 0).eval() # cent_indices: [[6 0]\n [9 0]]
    indices_list.append(indices)
    for cent in cent_indices:
        if cent in indices:
           centers_list.append(cent)
           break
```

The first iteration `cent` has the value `[6 0]` but it enters the `if` condition.

**answer**

```
for index in xrange(max_indices):
    indices = tf.where(tf.equal(values, (index + 1))).eval()
    cent_indices = tf.where(centers > 0).eval()
    indices_list.append(indices)
    for cent in cent_indices:
        # batch_item is an iterator from an outer loop
        if values[batch_item, cent[0]].eval() == (index + 1):
           centers_list.append(tf.constant(cent))
           break
```

The solution is related to my task, but if you are looking for a solution in 1D tensor I suggest to have a look on `tf.sets.set_intersection`

Comment: In is an operator, not a built-in

Comment: "I've tried to evaluate and iterate over them using .eval() and checked if an element of t2 is in t1 using the built-in in, but doesn't work". Post the code and show the error.

Comment: Could you clarify your example ?

Comment: I'm taking some indices of values in a tensor, and other indices from another tensor, then I have to take from the second tensor not all the indices but only the index which is inside of the first tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you wanted ? I used just these two test cases.

```
x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]])
y = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]])
# x = tf.constant([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 7]])
# y = tf.constant([[7, 7], [3, 5]])

def match(xiterations, yiterations, yvalues, xvalues ):
    for i in range(xiterations):
        for j in range(yiterations):
            if (np.array_equal(yvalues[j], xvalues[i])):
                print( yvalues[j])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    xindex = tf.where( x > 4 )
    yindex = tf.where( y > 4 )

    xvalues = xindex.eval()
    yvalues = yindex.eval()

    xiterations =  tf.shape(xvalues)[0].eval()
    yiterations =  tf.shape(yvalues)[0].eval()

    print(tf.shape(xvalues)[0].eval())
    print(tf.shape(yvalues)[0].eval())

    if tf.shape(xvalues)[0].eval() >= tf.shape(yvalues)[0].eval():
        match( xiterations, yiterations, yvalues, xvalues)
    else:
        match( yiterations, xiterations, xvalues, yvalues)
```

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. Do you think it works also if the two tensors have different length? As in my example one of length 3 and one 2

Comment: Feeding with these `x = tf.constant([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 7]])` `y = tf.constant([[7, 7], [3, 5]])` as in my case, I get `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1,0], [1], and [1] instead`

Comment: I've solved in another way but, thanks for your time

Comment: You may also edit the answer or post another answer so that it is useful for others.